# How to change background in this PowerPoint slide?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, colors, microsoft-office-2016, color-theme

### Color of slide's background

I'm preparing a presentation for my University class, but I have a problem with changing color of my slide. Here's this particular slide:

One of my slides:

[image]

On the left there's this big white area - that's the one that I'd like to change color of.
I already tried Background formatting, but this setting changes the color of the blue area on the right. I can't manage to change the white color to something else.
I hope someone knows how it can be done. I'm using Office 2016.

Comment: Post a copy of the slide somewhere we can download it and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the background image is the blue one. The white space from the left is probably a shape. If you can't select it in edit mode you have to go and edit the master slide.

In PowerPoint go to: `View -> Slide Master`

Here you will have the slide master and under different layouts. Find the layout that has that white shape and there you can edit the color (or change it as you want).

After you make your edits, close the Slide Master View (You have that button in the Slide Master tab), go to your slide and from the `Home` Tab select the new Layout to your current slide.